# Can we assume power spectrum of a time domain signal form a polish space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a time domain signal and we perform Fourier Transform on and get the power spectrum. Can we consider that the power spectrum comes from a polish space? It is a set from polish space?

Comment: What is a Polish space?

Comment: @cameron it is topological space.

Comment: Fourier transform gives the power spectrum, it cannot distinguish between noise and signal, further we also get the side-lobe. The side lobe comes from window function. I was thinking to use some measure to remove the both noise and side-lobe. But to form it mathematically I need an appropriate algebra/space so I asked this question.